# Parse a JSON struct as a JSON object in Scala / Spark

Tags: json, scala, apache-spark

I store into my MongoDB collection a huge list of JSON strings. For simplicity, I have extracted a sample document into the text file `businessResource.json`:

```
{
   "data" : {
        "someBusinessData" : {
            "capacity" : {
                "fuelCapacity" : NumberLong(282)
            },
            "someField" : NumberLong(16),
            "anotherField" : {
                "isImportant" : true,
                "lastDateAndTime" : "2008-01-01T11:11",
                "specialFlag" : "YMA"
            },
   ...
}
```

**My problem**: how can I convert the "someBusinessData" into a JSON object using Spark/Scala?

If I do that (for example using json4s or lift-json), I hope I can perform basic operations on them, for example checking them for equality.

Have in mind that this is a rather large JSON object. Creating a case class is not worth it in my case since the only operation I will perform will be some filtering on two fields, comparing documents for equality, and then I will export them again.

This is how I fetch the data:

```
 val df: DataFrame = (someSparkSession).sqlContext.read.json("src/test/resources/businessResource.json")

 val myData: DataFrame = df.select("data.someBusinessData")
 myData.printSchema
```

The schema shows:

```
root
 |-- someBusinessData: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |-- capacity: struct (nullable = true)
```

Since "someBusinessData" is a structure, I cannot get it as String. When I try to print using 
`myData.first.getStruct(0)`, I get a string that contains the values but not the keys: `[[[282],16,[true,2008-01-01T11:11,YMA]`

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In fact, my post containd two questions:

1. How can I convert the "someBusinessData" into a JSON object using Spark/Scala?
2. How can I get the JSON object as a String?

**1. Conversion into a JSON object**

What I was doing, was already creating a DataFrame that can be navigated as a JSON object:

```
//read json file as Json and select the needed data
val df: DataFrame = sparkSession.sqlContext.read.json(filePath).select("data.someBusinessData")
```

If you do `.textFile` you correctly get the String, but parse the JSON you then need to resort to the answer from Shu.

**2. How can I get the JSON object as a String?**

Trivially:

```
    df.toJSON.first
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using `.json` use **`.textFile`** to read your json file.

- Then we convert `rdd` to `dataframe`(will have only one string column).

**`Example:`**

```
//read json file as textfile and create df

val df=spark.sparkContext.textFile("<json_file_path>").toDF("str")

//use get_json_object function to traverse json string
df.selectExpr("""get_json_object(str,"$.data.someBusinessData")""").show(false)

//+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
//|get_json_object(str,$.data.someBusinessData)                                                                                                         |
//+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
//|{"capacity":{"fuelCapacity":"(282)"},"someField":"(16)","anotherField":{"isImportant":true,"lastDateAndTime":"2008-01-01T11:11","specialFlag":"YMA"}}|
//+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

Comment: Do you imply that I have to install Apache Hive? Can it not be done with Spark / Scala / json4s / lift-web json instead?

Comment: Does the answer meet your requirements? and No need to install hive, We are using spark-scala!

Comment: I quickly tried to use it. What's the import and/or the sbt dependency for "get_json_object"? Btw, it was not me that down-voted you :)

Comment: lets continue in chat: https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/209779/room-for-shu-and-user1485864